# Расположение окна по центру Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как задать расположение окна по центру экрана?

Answer (score 8):

Примерно так (один из ответов гугла):

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
root.mainloop()
```